# Python in-place operator (as "+="), numpy array and identity function not working properly?

Tags: python, numpy, operator-keyword, in-place

The arrays `yn` and `zn` are equals numericaly speaking, but there is an odd difference:
the line `yn += 7`, as expected, does not change `tn` array, but the second last line `zn += 7` changes `tn` array!

This is the code:

```
import numpy as np
def f(x): return (1*x)
def g(x): return (x)
nn = 5
tn = np.zeros(nn)
yn = np.zeros(nn)
zn = np.zeros(nn)

tn = np.linspace(0,1,nn)
yn = f(tn)
zn = g(tn)

print('tn at step1 =',tn)
yn += 7  #as expected, this line does not change tn.
print('tn at step2 =',tn)
zn += 7  #why this line adds 7 to tn array?!
print('tn at step3 =',tn)
```

The output is:

```
tn at step1 = [ 0.    0.25  0.5   0.75  1.  ]
tn at step2 = [ 0.    0.25  0.5   0.75  1.  ]
tn at step3 = [ 7.    7.25  7.5   7.75  8.  ] *why is 7 added to tn array?!*
```

Notice that are involved:

- numpy array
- g(x) as identity function
- in-place iadd operator (+=)

Although I have solved this problem using `zn = zn + 7` instead `zn += 7` my question is: why in the second last line `zn += 7` changes `tn` array?

Comment: A couple of coding points.  The initial `zeros` definitions of `tn` etc are overwritten by later assignments. you don't need them.  In `g`, the `()` doesn't add anything.  Use `return x`, or as recommended in the answer `return x.copy()`.

Answer (score 7):

When you define `g()`, you make it return its argument unchanged.  Because of that, when you say `zn = g(tn)`, you are in effect saying `zn = tn`.  Therefore, `zn` is now just another name for `tn`.  The `+=` operator is not *quite* the exact duplicate of `x = x +`.  It generally does the same thing, but in the background it is calling a method named `__iadd__`.  Since `zn` and `tn` are now the same object, you are calling `tn`'s `__iadd__` method.  Because of that, `tn` is modified.  To change that, you could say `zn = tn.copy()` when you first define it; or you could say `zn = zn + 7` when you try to add 7.